# Hibernate (XML mapping) insert fail

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

I'm trying to insert a new register but when Hibernate creates the insert it doesn't put the FK value.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ar.com.grupo1.entity.Turno" table="Turno">
        <id name="numeroTurno" type="int">
            <column name="Id_Turno" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nombrePaciente" type="string">
            <column name="Nombre" length="60" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="apellidoPaciente" type="string">
            <column name="Apellido" length="60" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="planMedico" type="string">
            <column name="PlanMedico" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="fechaLlegada" type="string">
            <column name="FechaHoraLlegada" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="fechaAtencion" type="string">
            <column name="FechaHoraAtencion" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="importe" type="float">
            <column name="Importe" />
        </property>
        <property name="observaciones" type="string">
            <column name="Observaciones" length="250" />
        </property>

        <one-to-one name="prestador" class="ar.com.grupo1.entity.Prestador"></one-to-one>

        <one-to-one name="practica" class="ar.com.grupo1.entity.Practica"></one-to-one>

        <one-to-one name="socio" class="ar.com.grupo1.entity.Socio" constrained="true"></one-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

On the insert is there isn't the Id_Socio value.

> INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: insert into Turno (Nombre,
>   Apellido, PlanMedico, FechaHoraLlegada, FechaHoraAtencion, Importe,
>   Observaciones) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> WARN [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 515, SQLState: 23000
>
> ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Værdien NULL kan ikke indsættes i
>   kolonnen 'Id_Socio', tabellen 'grupo1.dbo.Turno'. Kolonnen tillader
>   ikke null-værdier. INSERT kan ikke udføres.

**UPDATE**

I've already checked that the Socio's, Practica's, and Prestador's ID exists in the database. 
I'm giving to Turnos all these classes as attributes, it gets them correctly but at the time it does the Insert operation, is not inserting the FK values.

Comment: Hard to tell without more information, but perhaps you didn't make a corresponding socio entry? That's probably why it can't find the Id_Socio value.

Comment: @greatchi sorry, class Turno has all values filled, including Socio object(which has the ID inside it). Already checked that the Socio exists in database.